# How do I set Handbrake to default to mkv Matroska format?

Tags: handbrake

I use Handbrake to rip DVDs to Matroska mkv format files, but I keep forgetting to choose Matroska from the format dropdown for each video.

I can't find any way to set this as the default. It looks like I should be able to create a preset that uses Matroska, but I can't see how.

Is there a way?

Using Handbrake 0.10

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Settings like the format are tied to the individual presets. You can either modify / create a preset, or make one of the default Matroska presets your default.

It looks like the preset management has moved a bit between versions. Here it is in 0.9.9 (xubuntu 14.04):
[image: preset management options for 0.9.9]

NOTE: in screenshot above the arrow points to all 3 buttons below the preset list.

Here it is in 1.0.1 (manjaro update 2017-01-30):

[image: Preset management menu in Handbrake 1.0.1]

Comment: I have no buttons on my handbrake presets dialog!!! I added the screenshot as evidence. Guess I need to wait for the upgrade to make its way into Mint. I thought I might be able to 'export' a preset but it requires a substantial xml document *.plist which looks difficult to get right.

Comment: Yours does not look like it has the buttons below the Presets List. However, it does look like it has the Presets menu item (look at the 2nd screenshot in my answer). Does that have what you're looking for?

Comment: Guess I should export preset "Normal", edit the XML to set the format to Matroska, and re-import it.

Answer (score 0):

> Using Handbrake 0.10

you should absolutely [update it](https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/ubuntu/handbrake-releases)